# Importing variable from main in another module

Tags: python

I have a module that imports a variable in the main.py script, however, I get an error like so: `ImportError: cannot import name 'process'` However, it is caused by the variable that is imported from main after I checked the traceback statement and by removing the import statement it works. Here's how my directory structure looks like:

```
-Example
 -src
  -dispatch
      -__init__.py
      -process.py
  -__init__
  -main.py
```

In `process.py` I use this import statement `from src.main import spark` and that is how the error occurs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a classic Python circular import problem.

Move from src.main import spark inside the function thats using it in your process.py file

or

create a third file maybe called it shared.py and import there from main.py and process.py

Comment: Create a third file and import both what?